# Grep Multiple words using a pattern

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, cut

I ahve a requirement where i need to grep multiple strings from a log file if the pattern is matched

below is the log snapshot:access.log

```
12.12.137.16 - RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:17 -0700] "GET /identity/afr/partition/ie/n/default/opt/grid-11.1.1.9.0-5358.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9318 
12.12.137.16 - BMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:17 -0700] "GET /identity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6788 
12.12.137.16 - RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:17 -0700] "GET /identity/afr/partition/ie/n/default/opt/status-11.1.1.9.0-5358.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2297 
12.12.137.16 - RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:17 -0700] "GET /identity/afr/partition/ie/n/default/opt/poll-11.1.1.9.0-5358.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2098 
12.12.137.16 - RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:18 -0700] "GET /identity/afr/alta-v1/overflow_right_ena.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1082 
12.12.137.16 - RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:18 -0700] "GET /identity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6749 
12.12.137.16 - RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:18 -0700] "GET /identity/afr/alta-v1/conv_l_ena.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1161 
12.12.137.16 - RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:24 -0700] "GET /identity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6799 
12.12.137.16 - RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:27 -0700] "GET /identity/images/Dashboard/myAccess_s2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6885 
12.12.137.16 - SSS1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:24 -0700] "POST /identity/faces/home?_adf.ctrl-state=o9l9q161v_5 HTTP/1.1" 200 41776
```

want to grep the username and time fields if the pattern matches `/identity /HTTP/1.1`  in the log file

so my output will be:

```
BMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:17
RMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:18 
RMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:24
```

Tried:

```
grep -E '/identity/ HTTP/1.1' *.log
```

But it is giving whole line.

Please assist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -F'[][ ]+' '/\/identity\/ HTTP\/1[.]1/{print $3,$4}' access.log 
BMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:17
RMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:18
RMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:24
```

How it works:

- `-F'[][ ]+'`

  This sets the field separator to be any combination of `[`, `]`, or space.
- `/\/identity\/ HTTP\/1[.]1/{print $3,$4}`

  This selects the lines of interest and prints just the third and fourth fields.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -n '\|/identity/ HTTP/1[.]1|{s/^.* - //; s/[[]//; s/[]].*//; p;}' access.log 
BMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:17 -0700
RMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:18 -0700
RMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:24 -0700
```

How it works:

- `-n`

  This tells sed not print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `\|/identity/ HTTP/1[.]1|`

  This selects the lines of interest.
- `s/^.* - //; s/[[]//; s/[]].*//`

  For the selected lines, these three substitution commands remove the unwanted parts from the line.
- `p`

  This tells sed to print what is left of the selected lines after our substitutions were made.

#### Using `grep -P`

If your grep supports the `-P` flag:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<= - ).*(?= "GET /identity/ HTTP/1\.1)' access.log 
BMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:17 -0700]
RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:18 -0700]
RMC1 [06/Jul/2016:07:34:24 -0700]
```

If it is important to get rid of `[` and `]`, we can use:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<= - ).*(?=] "GET /identity/ HTTP/1\.1)' access.log | tr -d '['
BMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:17 -0700
RMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:18 -0700
RMC1 06/Jul/2016:07:34:24 -0700
```

Comment: +1 for good answer, but just a note though, your `grep` answer isn't producing what OP wanted. OP did not want `[` and `]` characters.

Comment: You need to escape `.` in the pattern, it will match any char now between two 1s (e.g. 1x1, 131 etc.) not that it's realistic in this scenario.

Comment: @karakfa Yes, thanks, I missed that a couple places.  Answer updated.

Comment: @sps Good point.  I just added a `grep+tr` solution to handle that.